# Как сравнить элементы массива между собой в JS?

Tags: javascript

```
Let arr = [‘январь’,’февраль’, ‘март’,]
```

Если все элементы массива равны между собой то вернуть в консоль true, если не равны то false.

Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Сравнить всё с первым элементом. Если хоть один не совпадает, то вывести false.

Comment: `console.log(arr.every(item => item === arr[0]))` - и желательно в функцию вынести с проверкой, что массив имеет хотя бы 1 элемент.

Answer (score 0):

###### TL;DR

```js
arr.every(item => item === arr[0])
```

###### Объяснение

`arr.every` берёт каждый элемент массива (в данном случае `arr`), и применяет callback (в данном случае `item => item === arr[0]`). Если все вызовы callback вернули положительное значение (например, `true`, число больше 1), то функция `arr.every` возвращает `true`, если нет - возвращает `false`.

Теперь о самой функции `callback`. Код этой функции:

```js
item => item === arr[0]
```

В данном случае эта функция передаётся аргументом в функцию `arr.every` и проверяет, что аргумент `item` равняется первому элементу (`arr[0]`), и если так, возвращает `true`, а если нет, `false`.

###### Дополнение

Этот код лучше объявить как функцию в коде, чтобы не повторять одно и тоже:

```js
function everyItemsSameInarr(arr) {
    return arr.every(item => item === arr[0]);
}
```

Потом можно использовать так, для примера:

```js
if (everyItemsSameInarr(items)) {
    // сделать что-то
    console.log("Все элементы равны");
}
```